# Converting from frequency domain to time domain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, mathematics

If I have an equation of a signal in the frequency domain given by

$$L(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\frac{1}{2}\Gamma}{((\omega-\omega_0)^2+(\frac{1}{2}\Gamma)^2)}$$

and I want to convert this to the time domain, can I do this using the inverse Fourier transform? I think the result should be an exponential, but when I tried to calculate this on mathematica I got a strange result.

Comment: Why don't you show us what Mathematica gave you?    This looks like the square modulus of  a typical signal's Fourier transform, not the transform itself.  Did Mathematica give you a damped sinusoid?

Comment: I just used the mathematica expression

$FourierTransform[2.5/(Pi*((x - 97.5)^2 + 2.5^2)), x, t]$

which returns

   $ 0.795775 exp((-2.5 + 97.5 I) t) (0.501326 exp(5. t) HeavisideTheta[-t] + 0.501326 HeavisideTheta[t])$

Comment: The result looks reasonable as it reflects the distinction of case for $t>0$ and $t<0$  (the Heaviside function shows this)  which has to be applied to make the complex path integral convergent.

Comment: All ok.  Except that $L(x)$ *looks* like a power spectral density (PSD) rather than a spectrum.  If that's correct, the Fourier transform will give the autocorelation function of the original signal, not the original signal itself.    I'd expect the autocorrelation function to be a damped sinusoid.  And that's what Mathematica produced.

Answer (score 2):

It's a standard integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {d\omega}{2\pi} \frac {(\Gamma/2)}{\omega^2+(\Gamma/2)^2} e^{i\omega t}= \frac 12 e^{-\Gamma |t|/2}.
$$
You should not have to use Mathematica for this! You can check the answer by evaluating the FT of $e^{-\Gamma |t|/2}$ which is elementary -- no contour integrals required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the Fourier integral  $\int L \exp(i\omega t) \frac{d\omega}{2\pi}$  easily by the application of the theorem of residues. First you look for the poles in the complex plane, second you choose the integration path (either a half-circle in the upper or in the lower complex plane, actually a  distinction of cases has to be done for $t>0$ and $t<0$) checking that the integrand converges to zero on the half-circular part at  infinity), and finally can apply the formula of the residue theorem which is essentially

$\oint f(\omega)  d\omega   = 2\pi i \sum\limits_{k=1,\ldots  n} Res(f,\omega_k)$   with $f(\omega) = \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{a  \exp(i\omega t )}{(\omega-\omega_1)(\omega-\omega_2)}$    with $\omega_1 = \omega_0 +ia$ and  $\omega_2= \omega_0 -ia$  and $a = \frac{1}{2}\Gamma$

where $\omega_k$ is the k-th pole which is surrounded by the integral path.  As the chosen half-circle (the integration path) only encircles one pole the expression  Res(f) gives:  $Res(f,\omega_{1/2}) = f(\omega)\cdot (\omega-\omega_{1/2})|_{\omega=\omega_{1/2}}$  1 or 2  has to be chosen depending on which pole is encircled by the integration path.