# Evolution of a quantum state due to a pulse

Tags: schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

I have some Lorentzian pulse with equation

$L(\omega)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\frac{1}{2}\Gamma}{((\omega-\omega_0)^2+(\frac{1}{2}\Gamma)^2)}$

with Fourier transform

$F(t)=e^{(-2\pi it\omega_0-\Gamma\pi|t|)} $.

I want to act this pulse on the density matrix of a quantum state in the time domain, e.g.

$\rho=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

I tried to do this by setting the pulse to be along the $z$ axis and constructing an evolution of the form

$U=F(t)\sigma_z$

where $\sigma_z$ is the Pauli $z$ operator and then acting this on $\rho$, i.e.

$\rho_{out}=U\rho U^{\dagger}$

but the output I get from this is either wrong or not normalised. Do I just need to add a normalisation factor or is my model incorrect?

The parameters I use are $\omega_0=97.5$MHz and $\Gamma=5$MHz

Comment: The matrix $\rho$ you started with is not a valid density matrix. A valid density matrix must (1) have non-negative diagonal entries, (2) have tr$\rho=1$, (3) be Hermitian. In your case, tr$\rho=0$, so it can't even be normalized.

Comment: This appears to be a follow-on to [your earlier question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/399128/5739).  I will point out that your $L(\omega)$ is identical to the power spectral density function of a quasi-monochromatic function, and your $F(t)$ is the autocorrelation of that function.  These facts raise a caution flag for me.  You may be on solid ground with what you are trying to do, but it's possible that you aren't.   Where did you get $L(\omega)$?

Comment: $L(ω)$ comes from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html. It says here that the Fourier transform is the exponential function I've written above.